# Why is IE9 ignoring my CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to turn off user-select, and I'm using the following comprehensive CSS:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

For firefox and chrome, works perfectly. In IE9, however, the inspector tells me that it simply doesn't see those lines of CSS. It's taking all the other CSS out of the exact same set-- the other style rules for that element are all there-- it's just ignoring these lines completely!!

Why won't IE9 detect my user-select controls??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3900798 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/826782

Comment: Yeppp....tracked it back over to the massive 200k view question and found the answer in one of the answers that isn't checked. I'll answer it myself later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, in IE versions preceding IE10, you can't use that CSS. You have to manually apply an `unselectable="on"` attribute to all the divs you wish to make unselectable.

See the second highest answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting) for more info.